# integrate product of trig functions

Tags: integration, trigonometric-series

I need to find the Fourier cosine series for $\cos(3x)\sin^2(x)$, But I don't even know where to start to determine $$\int _0^{\pi }\cos(3x)\sin^2(x)\cos(k x)dx$$

Answer (score 4):

$$
\sin^2 x = \frac12 - \frac12\cos(2x).
$$
$$
\cos(3x)\left(\frac12 - \frac12\cos(2x)\right) = \frac12\cos(3x) - \frac12\cos(3x)\cos(2x).
$$

\begin{align}
& \cos(3x)\cos(2x) - \sin(3x)\sin(2x) = \cos(5x) \\
& \cos(3x)\cos(2x) + \sin(3x)\sin(2x) = \cos(x) \\  \\
\text{Therefore } & \cos(3x)\cos(2x) = \frac{\cos(5x)+\cos(x)}{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You can express $\sin^2 x=\frac 12 - \frac 12 \cos 2x$.  The first term will give zero unless $k=3$.  For the second term you should be able to express $\cos 3x \cos 2x$ as a sum of the from $a \cos 5x + b \cos x$ and then argue you need $k=1$ or $5$ to not get zero.